# Teradata 12.0: Referential Integrity Constraint

Tags: constraints, teradata, referential-integrity

Is it possible to add a referential integrity constraint on a column which references a non primary-key column in another table.

I basically have a table with an ID column **which is non-unique**.

I have another table with REFERENCE column which refers to the ID column in the above table.

I want to enforce a constraint on REFERENCE column that it only contain values present in the ID column.

Can this be done through the Reference Constraint in Teradata 12.0?

thanks